# Importing project of Github issue

Tags: android-studio

I've downloaded a project from github and while importing it into my android studio I'm facing this error:

> Illegal character in path at index 9: D:/Google Drive/Dev/Android/weather_alarm_clock_key.jks

Can anyone help?

Comment: Which project is it?

Comment: its weather alarm clock

Answer (score 0):

Download it to a folder without a space in it. That's what it's complaining about, according to the limited information you provided.

Comment: there is no white space in the directory

Comment: @RahimaJahangir "Google Docs" has a space.

Comment: @RahimaJahangir Erm... From the place you downloaded it from in the first place?? But you could also copy it somewhere else.